# How to create MySQL Trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Can someone please help me with MySQL Trigger

Lets say I have two Tables

```
Table_Current
No (INT TYPE)
Name (VARCHAR TYPE)
Value (DECIMAL TYPE)

Table_Record
No (INT TYPE)
Name (VARCHAR TYPE)
Value (DECIMAL TYPE)
```

So what I want to achieve is that, I perform replace statements on Table.Current, and if the value of field 'Value' is smaller than that of the Value in Table.Record, I would like to update the Value of Table.Record,

Here is what I have as a trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER Mytrigger
AFTER INSERT ON Table_Current

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE CB DECIMAL (6,3);
DECLARE OB DECIMAL (6,3);

OB = SELECT Value FROM Table_Record WHERE Name=NEW.Name;
CB = NEW.Value;
IF CB<OB THEN
UPDATE Table_Record SET Value = NEW.Value WHERE Name = NEW.Name;
END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this massively.  What you are trying to do is effectively this query

```
    UPDATE Table_Record

    SET `Value` = NEW.`Value` 
    WHERE `Name` = NEW.`Name`
    AND `Value` < NEW.`Value`;
```

You are interested in updating the row in `Table_Record` where `Name` = `NEW.Name`. You only want to update if the `NEW.Value` is larger than the one currently stored.  Therefore the above will not update if that value constraint is not satisfied.

This trigger code should do what you are trying to achieve.

```
-- First of all, drop any other trigger with the same name
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `Mytrigger`;

-- Create the new trigger
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `Mytrigger`
AFTER INSERT ON Table_Current

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    UPDATE Table_Record

    SET `Value` = NEW.`Value` 
    WHERE `Name` = NEW.`Name`
    AND `Value` < NEW.`Value`;

END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: This version of mysql doest support multiple trigger..I am currently using xampp and the version of mysql is 5.0.51

Comment: Do you have any triggers set up already on `Table_Current`, you may need to drop your previous attempt.  Will add a row above into the query.

Comment: Thanks simon, i didnt realize that one of the attempt actually was correct.. and a trigger was already stored.. :)

Comment: Btw, can i create a trigger on "AFTER REPLACE" ?

Comment: @user1149126, you can create 6 kind of triggers, BEFORE/AFTER either INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. So yes, but it's called `AFTER UPDATE`

Comment: You can create triggers on `BEFORE|AFTER INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE` afaik, a `REPLACE` is an `UPDATE` in this scope.  For more info, check here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html